# What is the relationship between real analysis and topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have been brushing up on real analysis recently and, knowing nothing about topology but having seen some very general YT videos on the subject, I have developed a vague feeling that it somehow is very closely related to real analysis. For instance they both seem very concerned with continuity and continuous maps. Could someone please elaborate on the contact points between these branches of math?

Comment: Topology is in some sense a subset of Analysis. Topology is very concerned with ideas of continuity and what properties of sets are preserved under continuous transformations. Analysis is well analysis, any set involving real numbers (even some terribly pathological ones) are fair game. But where they also diverge is analysis might interest itself with ideas like the locations of 0s of a function or smoothness. Concepts which can shift or are too restrictive to be considered by some parts of topology.

Comment: The notions of continuity, open sets, connectedness, and many more seen in real analysis are exactly the same as those explored in topology. You just have more structure to use when exploring these ideas in the context of Euclidean spaces

Comment: A similar way to think about it is levels of abstraction. First you have real analysis on the real line or in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is generally focused on limits and continuity.  Then the next level of abstraction would be metric spaces where you still have a distance function.  Then in general topology you can further abstract the idea of continuity without necessarily having a metric, which leads to formulating everything in terms of open sets.

Comment: When people speak of topology having to do with not changing spaces via stretching without tearing, that is abstracting key properties from geometry and leads more towards algebraic than general topology.  But of course it's all related!

Comment: @AlgTop1854 hmm ok so in a sense, would you say that the study of metric spaces is a kind of generalisation of the real line; and the same for general topology and metric spaces? Or are they more distinct than that?

Comment: @ftv0 Not a matter of distinct, just more general (and abstract I suppose) at each step. Metric spaces absolutely generalize real analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the definition of metric takes the key properties from Euclidean distance.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 metric spaces generalize only a piece of real analysis. Metrics alone are not sufficient to express for example geometry (e.g. angles) or algebraic properties of reals.

Comment: Topology takes *some* aspects of continuity, and generalizes them, but only those aspects. Both are broad but in different direction.

Comment: To have a basic understanding of real analysis, you want to have a basic understanding of topology. But after introductory level, those two diverge.

Comment: I think [tag:differential-geometry] is a topic in between real analysis and topology. Or, one of the topics. To study it, you absolutely need to be familiar with both. But to some extent you can ignore some aspects. Early on you need not too much of the abstract analysis, and you can also ignore the more exotic topological structures given that  manifolds locally look like the Euclidean space (but there is interesting global topology going on, and various kinds of singularities). I'm not an expert on any of these themes, but I thought this is worth a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, continuity is an important topic in both real analysis and topology. But to say that they are very close because of that is an exaggeration in my humble opinion.

So topology is an abstract framework that deals with open subsets, continuity and general shapes. It covers ideas such as: how to deform one shape into another. How to distinguish one shape from another?

Real analysis, on the other hand, deals with real numbers and their extensions. So it doesn't cover all the abstract shapes that a topology may generate. But on the other hand it deals with stuff that are not expressible through topology alone, e.g. the very rich algebraic structure of reals.

First of all it (mostly) deals with metrics. It is true that each metric induces a topology such that the concept of open subsets and continuity coincides. However not every topology arises from a metric, and more importantly, even if it does, it never arises from a unique metric (except for trivial cases of empty set and singleton). Meaning we always have multiple metrics that induce the same topology (in fact always infinitely many). Does it mean a concrete choice of metric doesn't matter? That depends on what we are trying to achieve. For example if a mathematical framework is supposed to serve some real world calculations, then the choice of metric matters a lot.

Secondly, real analysis deals with much more than just metrics/topology. It also makes heavy use of algebraic structure of the reals. The most important examples are [differential calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus) and [integral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral). Topology or metric alone are not enough to cover these concepts. Another feature of reals that abstract topology/metric is not capable of covering is the ordering of reals. Which is again very important.

All in all, metrics generalize some features of reals. But not all. Topology generalizes some features of metrics. But not all.

Comment: These are good points; I would not contend that metric spaces fully subsume analysis on the reals nor that topology fully subsumes metric spaces, rather that abstracting a few key ideas once then again leading to how open sets and continuity are defined in general spaces is ONE way to think about the progression and how parts of it arose historically.